# Deploy WPF Application Build to VM on Azure from TFS

Tags: wpf, azure, deployment, tfs

I am wanting to deploy basically the bin folder to a VM that is hosted on Azure. I want to deploy from my TFS 2015 Server to a Window 7 VM which are both hosted in Azure. I have set up a Machine File Copy task and tried to get it to point to the correct VM but nothing seems to work. It continually comes back with the error :

```
2015-12-29T14:27:30.5763871Z ##[debug]Initiating copy on machine-name    
2015-12-29T14:27:57.0124127Z ##[debug]Finished copy operation on machine-name    
2015-12-29T14:27:57.0280368Z ##[debug]Deployment logs for copy operation on machine-name    
2015-12-29T14:27:57.0280368Z ##[debug]System.AggregateException: Failed to execute the powershell script. Consult the logs below for details of the error.    
2015-12-29T14:27:57.0280368Z System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to the path \\machine-name with the user username for copying. System error 53 has occurred.     
2015-12-29T14:27:57.0280368Z  The network path was not found.
```

I changed the machine name and username in the above snippet.

I have followed most of the steps in these articles:

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/20/build-vnext-support-for-deploying-bits-to-windows-machines/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/31/dev-test-in-azure-and-deploy-to-production-on-premises.aspx

But I could not see the option for Azure File Copy so that's out the window. When I use PsPing I can connect from the TFS Server to the target VM when targeting the specific WinRM port 5985.

I am not sure if what I am trying to achieve is even possible with TFS + Azure, but I would have imagined this is exactly the type of scenario Azure was built for?!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the add Step Dialog:
[image]

Comment: Can you use Release Management for this? Release Management vNext with PowerShell support or even better, Release Management vNextNext hosted in Visual Studio Team Services.

Comment: Seems like it could do the trick. Thanks, I'll look into it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **Azure File Copy** task to copy files to Azure VMs. Open the build definition, and click **Add build step**... -> go to Deploy page on the ADD TASKS dialog. Then you will find the Azure File Copy task. See:

[image]

However, you mentioned that the task is missing, can you share me the screenshot of the ADD TASKS dialog?

Comment: I have edited my original post to show the add new step dialog. I am wondering if the TFS server is missing some plugins or something.

Comment: @stuartmclark, in order to use the Azure File Copy task, you need to upgrade your TFS2015 to TFS2015 Update 1. After the TFS server is upgraded, you will get that task. You can get the update: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/tfs2015-update1-vs.aspx

Comment: Ah that's great. I'll do that when I get back from my holidays. Thanks again.